# Creating New JLabel From Database

Tags: java, sql, swing, dynamic, jpanel

thanks for all the help. here's the information you might need to answer my q:

#### what do I want

create a JLabel for each item in the SQL database table and display it on a JPanel. when a new item is added to the db, a new label is created and displayed.

#### what problem I encounter

currently, my code only creates a JLabel for the last item in the db. also the JLabel does not change when new information is added to the db. [this is how it looks](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1T2C7.png)

#### code for adding JLabel

I use this code in my `public mainPanel()` method, after `this.$$$setupUI$$$();`. creating this code in `createUIComponents()` throws a NullPointerException

```
            LinkedList<Task> allTasks = new LinkedList<Task>();


            final String username = "root";
            final String password = "password";
            final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";

            Statement statement;
            Connection connection;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                  throwables.printStackTrace();
                  throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            try {
                  statement = connection.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                  throwables.printStackTrace();
                  throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                  rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tasks");
                  while (rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("taskName");

                        Task taskFromDB = new Task();
                        taskFromDB.setTaskName(name);

                        allTasks.add(taskFromDB);
                  }

                  int i = allTasks.size();

                  for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                        JLabel newTaskNameLabel = new JLabel();
                        newTaskNameLabel.setText(allTasks.get(c).getTaskName());
                        Tasklist.add(newTaskNameLabel);
                        Tasklist.revalidate();
                  }


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException classNotFoundException) {
                  classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I'm working in IntelliJ IDEA.

#### EDIT

Here's the full code for the panel:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.sql.*;
import java.util.Calendar;
import java.util.GregorianCalendar;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import javax.swing.*;

public class mainPanel extends JPanel {

      public JPanel mainMenu;

      private JTabbedPane tabbedPane1; // tabbed pane
      private JPanel Schedule; // inner schedule panel
      private JPanel Tasklist; // inner tasklist panel
      private JPanel Reminders; // inner reminders panel
      private JButton addTaskButton;
      private JPanel buttonPanel2;

      public mainPanel() {

            this.$$$setupUI$$$();

            LinkedList<Task> allTasks = new LinkedList<Task>();

            final String username = "root";
            final String password = "password";
            final String URL = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/database";

            Statement statement;
            Connection connection;
            ResultSet rs = null;

            try {
                  connection = DriverManager.getConnection(URL, username, password);
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                  throwables.printStackTrace();
                  throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            try {
                  statement = connection.createStatement();
            } catch (SQLException throwables) {
                  throwables.printStackTrace();
                  throw new RuntimeException();
            }
            try {
                  Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
                  rs = statement.executeQuery("SELECT * FROM tasks");
                  while (rs.next()) {
                        String name = rs.getString("taskName");

                        Task taskFromDB = new Task();
                        taskFromDB.setTaskName(name);

                        allTasks.add(taskFromDB);
                  }

                  int i = allTasks.size();

                  for (int c = 0; c < i; c++) {
                        JLabel newTaskNameLabel = new JLabel();
                        newTaskNameLabel.setText(allTasks.get(c).getTaskName());
                        Tasklist.add(newTaskNameLabel);
                        Tasklist.revalidate();
                  }


            } catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException classNotFoundException) {
                  classNotFoundException.printStackTrace();
            }


            addTaskButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                  @Override
                  public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                        // create a task frame when button clicked
                        // task frame holds task panel
                        taskFrame tf = new taskFrame();
                        tf.setVisible(true);
                        tf.pack();
                  }
            });
      }

      /**
       * Method generated by IntelliJ IDEA GUI Designer
       * >>> IMPORTANT!! <<<
       * DO NOT edit this method OR call it in your code!
       *
       * @noinspection ALL
       */
      private void $$$setupUI$$$() {
            createUIComponents();
            mainMenu = new JPanel();
            mainMenu.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            mainMenu.setForeground(new Color(-10606236));
            tabbedPane1 = new JTabbedPane();
            mainMenu.add(tabbedPane1, BorderLayout.CENTER);
            Schedule = new JPanel();
            Schedule.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            tabbedPane1.addTab("Schedule", Schedule);
            Tasklist = new JPanel();
            Tasklist.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            tabbedPane1.addTab("Tasklist", Tasklist);
            buttonPanel2 = new JPanel();
            buttonPanel2.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            Tasklist.add(buttonPanel2, BorderLayout.NORTH);
            addTaskButton = new JButton();
            addTaskButton.setText("Add Task");
            buttonPanel2.add(addTaskButton, BorderLayout.EAST);
            Reminders = new JPanel();
            Reminders.setLayout(new BorderLayout(0, 0));
            tabbedPane1.addTab("Reminders", Reminders);
      }

      /**
       * @noinspection ALL
       */

      public JComponent $$$getRootComponent$$$() {
            return mainMenu;
      }

      private void createUIComponents() {

      }


}
```

Comment: what line throws that Exception? What variable is null? Have you debugged your code?

Comment: @Stultuske exception is only thrown when I use the code in CreateUIComponents() method (an IntelliJ IDEA method to create components without GUI form), but I'm not using it. I use `public mainPanel()`, and no exceptions are thrown .

Comment: "the JLabel does not change when new information is added to the db" - What exactly do you expect to happen? That the label updates if you change the data using a SQL client? If so then please note that your application would have to constantly watch for changes, just changing the database would not automagically send over the change to the application and cause a repaint.

Comment: "I'm not using it" "an IntelliJ IDEA method" ... if it's not used, it doesn't throw Exceptions. There are no "IntelliJ IDEA methods".

Comment: "my code only creates a JLabel for the last item in the db" - Did you debug your code (i.e. step through it with a debugger, not "visual" debugging) and check how many items have been returned and how many labels have been created? Could it be that all labels are stacked on top of each other (we don't know the layout manager used by the panel)? Also `Tasklist.add(...)` looks like a static method - is it or did you just not stick to the naming convention?

Comment: can you post the full code and a stacktrace?

Comment: @Thomas I would like to create a new JLabel for each new item in a database table. How do I implement "constantly watching for changes"? I haven't tried debugging, thanks! what does it mean if it's a static method?

Comment: @Stultuske well, that's what I'm saying, my code does not throw exceptions now. It only throws it when I move this part of the code into another place.

Comment: @geco17 ok, 1 sec

Comment: "Constantly watching for changes" might mean you use Change Data Capture (complex) or periodically query the database and rebuild the task list. A static method by itself deosn't have to be bad but it might be an indicator that you have some error in there and thus we might need to see that method.

Comment: @geco17 what is a stacktrace

Comment: @Thomas i posted the whole code

Comment: @alexandra a stacktrace is the printout of the null pointer that gets thrown

Comment: `TaskList` uses `BorderLayout` which doesn't fit your requirements, i.e. just calling `add(label)` would put each label in the same place and replaces any component already in that place. Try using `FlowLayout`, `GridLayout` etc. instead (and read the JavaDocs first).

Comment: @Thomas thank you!! the labels are showing, though when I add a new item into the database, it is not displayed until I close the program and run it again. i will now try to make it all look good (so far the labels are all stuff together) and make sure that the panel is updating !! THANK SO YOU MUCH once again